# Get_terms stopped working after WP 4.2

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I just noticed on my site that the custom taxonomy terms are no longer out putting.  I am only guessing that it's happened since the 4.2 update.  Here is the php:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'bw_filters' );
$genres = get_terms( 'bw_filters' , array( 'child_of' => 5   ) );
$terms_ids = array();
$genres_ids = array();
$output_terms = array();
foreach( $terms as $term ){
    $terms_ids[ $term->term_id ] = $term->term_id;
}
foreach( $genres as $term ){
    $genres_ids[ $term->term_id ] = $term->term_id;
}
foreach( $terms_ids as $term ){
    if( in_array( $term , $genres_ids ) ){
        $output_terms[] = $terms[ $term ];
    }
}

$count = count( $output_terms );
$i = 1;
foreach( $output_terms as $term ){
    echo $term->name;
    if( $i < $count ){
        echo ', ';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

I had someone else write this a long time ago, so I may not have answers to all questions about the code snippet.

I suspect it's the get_terms function that's no longer working as it should.  Previously, this code worked fine, and it would display children of ID 5.  Not it outputs nothing at all.  Just blank.

Any ideas are helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try passing 'bw_filters' as `array('bw_filters')` at the `get_terms` function?

Comment: `get_terms` just accepts another argument for the second parameter now, nothing in it changed that would affect this code, there is almost certainly another issue.  @fischi a string *should* work just as well as an array, but it's worth a shot.  MarkC, can you verify that both `$terms` and `$genres` are populated with values?

Answer (score 1):

I've got this fixed now.  Managed to talk with my old developer and he added this:

```
$termsById = array();
foreach ($terms as $t) {
    $termsById[$t->term_id] = $t;
}
```

I had to add this new variable where $terms was previously used on line 14.

Thanks for your help everyone, I appreciate the effort.